Is the Unit Scale setting available in the material editor?
There are material and texture properties which are made in scene units. (For example texture scaling, bump distance, etc.)
Using the same material in different units (meters vs.  millimeters) with different unit scaling make the texture look "wrong".
Is there a way to reference the scene's unit scaling setting directly in the material editor?

Why is there no option to use a custom shader attribute in the attribute node in the material editor? That could be driven directly by the unit scale. Is there really no way to get around this? I can't believe that there is no solution for such an important problem.
